# Jquery related help needed

Tags: jquery

I have created two classes using HTML and CSS in my website.
Now I added script to header file in wordpress to select a class among the two, but it is not working at all. Below is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$j=jQuery.noConflict();

// Use jQuery via $j(...)
$j(document).ready(function(){
$j("#followers").click(function(){

    $('.followers').addClass('active');
    $('.likes').removeClass('active');

});
 $j("#likes").click(function(){

    $('.followers').removeClass('active');
    $('.likes').addClass('active');

});

});

</script>
```

Comment: I was all ready to help, right up until I saw "buyinstagramfollowerzz"

Comment: It was just to show example, that code is not working.

Comment: @Blazemonger For real... I'd rather not be a part of whatever this is...

Comment: Maybe you should start by solving the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" errors on the bootstrap.js file included in your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code is conflicting. Use $j everywhere instead of just using it at two places.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$j=jQuery.noConflict();

// Use jQuery via $j(...)
$j(document).ready(function(){
$j("#followers").click(function(){

    $j('.followers').addClass('active');
    $j('.likes').removeClass('active');

});
 $j("#likes").click(function(){

    $j('.followers').removeClass('active');
    $j('.likes').addClass('active');

});

});

</script>
```